# Autoregression in nlme - undestanding how to specify corAR1

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation

I have a dataset of 12 days of diary data.
I am trying to use `lme` to model the effect of sleep quality on stress, with random intercept effects of participant and random slope effect of sleep quality. I am not particularly interested in asking whether there was change over time from diaryday 1 to 12, just in accounting for the time variable.

I'm much more familiar with `lme4` for multilevel models, but given my diary data structure, it seemed important to account for temporal autocorrelations in variance.

I've tried following model syntax from [here](https://m-clark.github.io/mixed-models-with-R/extensions.html), but I'm not totally clear on what the syntax actually means.

My question: What exactly does the syntax of `correlation = corAR1(form = ....)` specify? What is the difference between the `corAR1` syntax I have written in the two following models?

**Model 1:**

```
lme(stress_diary ~ sleepquality_diary + time.diary + diaryday + sex, 
data = data_diary,
random = ~ 1 + sleepquality_diary| randomid, 
correlation = corAR1(form = ~ diaryday | randomid), #What exactly am I specifying?
na.action=na.exclude)
```

**Model 2:**

```
lme(stress_diary ~ sleepquality_diary + time.diary + diaryday + sex, 
data = data_diary,
random = ~ 1 + sleepquality_diary| randomid, 
correlation = corAR1(), #What exactly am I specifying?
na.action=na.exclude)
```

Variables key:
stress_diary = a value from 1 to 5
sleepquality_diary = a value from 1 to 5
time.diary = time of day of response, from 00:00 (midnight)
diaryday = day of response, 1:12
sex = M,F
randomid = participant

I am quite new to time series and longitudinal diary data, so I know I am missing some of the intuitions.

Comment: `corAR1()` is the simplest correlation structure affecting only the intercept, `corAR1(form = ~ diaryday | randomid)` is specifying a correlation structure based on randomid (that is a different correlation structure for every randomid) which has an effect on both the intercept and the slope of the diaryday variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AR1 structure specifies that the correlations between the repeated measurements of each subject decrease with the time lag, i.e., the distance in time between the measurements.

When you specify `lme(..., correlation = corAR1())` this is equivalent to `lme(..., correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | id))` and assumes that the measurements are equally spaced.

When instead you specify `lme(..., correlation = corAR1(form = ~ time | id))` you use the time variable `time` to determine how far apart the measurements are, and define the time lag. Note, however, that `corAR1()` works with discrete time. There is also `corCAR1()` that works with continuous time.